# I can't seem to update scores

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm doing a post request to "https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/scores? score=USER_SCORE&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN"

With the right User_id, the right App Access token (not the user access token), but I keep getting a weird response.

The error message I get is : "A user access token is required to request this resource"

I also have the publish_actions permission for my user..

I you guys have any idea, I'm getting crazy here.